# How does a Celery worker consuming from multiple queues decide which to consume from first?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, celery, celeryd

I am using Celery to perform asynchronous background tasks, with Redis as the backend. I'm interested in the behaviour of a Celery worker in the following situation:

I am running a worker as a daemon using `celeryd`. This worker has been assigned two queues to consume through the `-Q` option:

```
celeryd -E -Q queue1,queue2
```

**How does the worker decide where to fetch the next task to consume from?** Does it randomly consume a task from either `queue1` or `queue2`? Will it prioritise fetching from `queue1` because it is first in the list of arguments passed to `-Q`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From my testing, it processes multiple queues **round-robin style**.

If I use this test code:

```
from celery import task
import time


@task
def my_task(item_id):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('Processing item "%s"...' % item_id)


def add_items_to_queue(queue_name, items_count):
    for i in xrange(0, items_count):
        my_task.apply_async(('%s-%d' % (queue_name, i),), queue=queue_name)


add_items_to_queue('queue1', 10)
add_items_to_queue('queue2', 10)
add_items_to_queue('queue3', 5)
```

And start the queue with (using django-celery):

```
`manage.py celery worker -Q queue1,queue2,queue3`
```

It outputs:

```
Processing item "queue1-0"...
Processing item "queue3-0"...
Processing item "queue2-0"...
Processing item "queue1-1"...
Processing item "queue3-1"...
Processing item "queue2-1"...
Processing item "queue1-2"...
Processing item "queue3-2"...
Processing item "queue2-2"...
Processing item "queue1-3"...
Processing item "queue3-3"...
Processing item "queue2-3"...
Processing item "queue1-4"...
Processing item "queue3-4"...
Processing item "queue2-4"...
Processing item "queue1-5"...
Processing item "queue2-5"...
Processing item "queue1-6"...
Processing item "queue2-6"...
Processing item "queue1-7"...
Processing item "queue2-7"...
Processing item "queue1-8"...
Processing item "queue2-8"...
Processing item "queue1-9"...
Processing item "queue2-9"...
```

So it pulls one item from each queue before going on to the next queue1 item even though ALL of the queue1 tasks were *published* before the queue2 & 3 tasks.

**Note:** As @WarLord pointed out, this exact behavior will only work when `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER` is set to 1.  If it's greater than 1, then that means items will be fetched from the queue in *batches*.  So if you have 4 processes with the PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER set to 4, that means there will be 16 items pulled from the queue right off the bat, so you won't get the exact output as above, but it will still *roughly* follow round-robin.

Comment: In 2019, This is not the correct answer, see correct and updated order from @crazyshezy The order now is based on arrival to queues.

Answer (score 9):

**NOTE:** This answer has deprecated: latest version of Celery works very differently then what it was in 2013...

A worker consuming several queues consumes task, FIFO order is maintained across multiple queues too.

Example:

Queue1 : (t1, t2, t5, t7) 
 Queue2 : (t0,t3,t4,t6)

Assuming 0-7 represents the order of the tasks published

order of Consumption is t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7

Comment: Is there any way to modify this behavior? Perhaps to give priority to one queue over another: t1, t2, t5, t7, t0, t3, t4, t6.

Comment: Not with RabbitMQ, could be possible with the other message transports e.g. with Redis but that would involve subclassing.  Note that the order you describe is actually starvation, if Queue1 is constantly busy the messages in Queue2 would never be processed.

Comment: @Crazyshezy - Are you saying that if I put 500 items into Queue1 and THEN put 1 item into Queue 2, that Queue 2 item won't get processed until the 500 items are done since it got there after them?? That seems to defeat the purpose of having multiple queues if it treats them as if they were just one queue...

Comment: From my testing, it processes the queues round-robin style, so, in your example, the Consumption order would be t1, t0, t2, t3, t5, t4, t7, t6.  Though, the order can vary, some, if you have PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER set to other-than 1 and the tasks take differing amounts of time to complete.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2192#issuecomment-51799123 it's determined by the _broker_. So Rabbit MQ seems to deliver in FIFO style, other brokers may do round robin I guess.

Comment: 2019 testing with RabbitMQ seems to suggest FIFO, which is indeed strange and seems to really defeat the purpose of multiple queues, really strange.

Comment: Interesting @JAR.JAR.beans, I was testing using the `pyamqp` broker library, interfacing with RabbitMQ, and I get an approximate round-robin behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Using the pyamqp broker library pointing at a rabbitmq server, tasks get processed in a round-robin style. See proof below.

It appears that the order tasks are processed in is determined by the broker *library*, not the actual backend (rabbitmq vs redis is not the issue).

Software versions:

```
$ pip freeze | egrep "celery|kombu|amqp"
amqp==2.5.2
celery==4.4.2
kombu==4.6.8
```

```py
from time import sleep

@app.task
def sleepy(name):
    print(f"Processing: {name}")
    sleep(0.5)
```

Then in another shell, queue the tasks:

```py
from time import sleep

def queue_them():
    for x in range(50):
        sleepy.apply_async(args=(f"Q1-T{x}",), queue="Q1")
    sleep(0.1)
    for x in range(20):
        sleepy.apply_async(args=(f"Q2-T{x}",), queue="Q2")
    sleep(0.1)
    sleepy.apply_async(args=("Q3-T0",), queue="Q3")
    for x in range(30):
        sleepy.apply_async(args=(f"Q2MOAR-T{x}",), queue="Q2")

# setup - get celery to setup the queues and exchanges
sleepy.apply_async(args=("nothing",), queue="Q1")
sleepy.apply_async(args=("nothing",), queue="Q2")
sleepy.apply_async(args=("nothing",), queue="Q3")

# run the test
queue_them()
```

And in another shell, run celery:

```
$ celery worker -A myapp.celery --pool=prefork --concurrency=2 -Ofair --queues=Q1,Q3,Q2

[2020-05-05 21:59:11,547] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T1
[2020-05-05 21:59:11,547] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T0
[2020-05-05 21:59:12,052] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T2
[2020-05-05 21:59:12,053] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T3
[2020-05-05 21:59:12,556] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T5
[2020-05-05 21:59:12,556] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T4
[2020-05-05 21:59:13,062] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T6
[2020-05-05 21:59:13,063] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T7
[2020-05-05 21:59:13,565] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T9
[2020-05-05 21:59:13,565] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T8
[2020-05-05 21:59:14,069] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T10
[2020-05-05 21:59:14,069] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q3-T0
[2020-05-05 21:59:14,571] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T0
[2020-05-05 21:59:14,572] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T1
[2020-05-05 21:59:15,078] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T11
[2020-05-05 21:59:15,078] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T2
[2020-05-05 21:59:15,581] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T3
[2020-05-05 21:59:15,581] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T12
[2020-05-05 21:59:16,084] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T13
[2020-05-05 21:59:16,084] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T4
[2020-05-05 21:59:16,586] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T14
[2020-05-05 21:59:16,586] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T5
[2020-05-05 21:59:17,089] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T15
[2020-05-05 21:59:17,089] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T6
[2020-05-05 21:59:17,591] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T16
[2020-05-05 21:59:17,592] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T7
[2020-05-05 21:59:18,094] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T17
[2020-05-05 21:59:18,094] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T8
[2020-05-05 21:59:18,597] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T18
[2020-05-05 21:59:18,597] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T9
[2020-05-05 21:59:19,102] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T19
[2020-05-05 21:59:19,102] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T20
[2020-05-05 21:59:19,607] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T21
[2020-05-05 21:59:19,607] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T22
[2020-05-05 21:59:20,110] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T23
[2020-05-05 21:59:20,110] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T10
[2020-05-05 21:59:20,614] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T24
[2020-05-05 21:59:20,614] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T11
[2020-05-05 21:59:21,118] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T25
[2020-05-05 21:59:21,118] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T26
[2020-05-05 21:59:21,622] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T12
[2020-05-05 21:59:21,622] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T27
[2020-05-05 21:59:22,124] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T28
[2020-05-05 21:59:22,124] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T13
[2020-05-05 21:59:22,627] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T14
[2020-05-05 21:59:22,627] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T29
[2020-05-05 21:59:23,129] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T31
[2020-05-05 21:59:23,129] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T30
[2020-05-05 21:59:23,631] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T15
[2020-05-05 21:59:23,632] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T32
[2020-05-05 21:59:24,134] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T33
[2020-05-05 21:59:24,134] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T16
[2020-05-05 21:59:24,636] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T17
[2020-05-05 21:59:24,636] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T18
[2020-05-05 21:59:25,138] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T19
[2020-05-05 21:59:25,139] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T34
[2020-05-05 21:59:25,641] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T35
[2020-05-05 21:59:25,642] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T0
[2020-05-05 21:59:26,144] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T36
[2020-05-05 21:59:26,144] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T37
[2020-05-05 21:59:26,649] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T1
[2020-05-05 21:59:26,649] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T38
[2020-05-05 21:59:27,153] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T2
[2020-05-05 21:59:27,154] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T39
[2020-05-05 21:59:27,656] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T3
[2020-05-05 21:59:27,656] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T4
[2020-05-05 21:59:28,159] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T5
[2020-05-05 21:59:28,160] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T40
[2020-05-05 21:59:28,664] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T6
[2020-05-05 21:59:28,664] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T41
[2020-05-05 21:59:29,167] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2MOAR-T7
[2020-05-05 21:59:29,167] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T42
```

And similar results when celery is run with a concurrency of 1:

```
[2020-05-05 22:01:33,879] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T0
[2020-05-05 22:01:34,385] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T1
[2020-05-05 22:01:34,888] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T2
[2020-05-05 22:01:35,391] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T3
[2020-05-05 22:01:35,894] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T4
[2020-05-05 22:01:36,397] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T5
[2020-05-05 22:01:36,899] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q3-T0
[2020-05-05 22:01:37,404] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T0
[2020-05-05 22:01:37,907] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T1
[2020-05-05 22:01:38,411] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T6
[2020-05-05 22:01:38,913] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T2
[2020-05-05 22:01:39,417] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T3
[2020-05-05 22:01:39,919] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T4
[2020-05-05 22:01:40,422] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T7
[2020-05-05 22:01:40,925] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q2-T5
[2020-05-05 22:01:41,429] WARNING [celery.redirected:235] Processing: Q1-T8
```

Comment: In a round-robin, I'd expect a consistent Q1>Q2>Q3, the log shows very different behavior, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

As of Celery 5.3, the queue priority is *to some extent* configurable when the Redis transport is used.

It can be adjusted first by changing the [queue order strategy](https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/v5.2.3/reference/kombu.transport.redis.html#kombu.transport.redis.Transport.Channel.queue_order_strategy), which is a Redis-specific [broker transport option](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/v5.3.1/userguide/configuration.html#broker-transport-options).

Its default value is `round_robin` which aims to give equal opportunity for every queue to be consumed from. One other available value is `priority`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/kombu/en/v5.2.3/reference/kombu.transport.redis.html#kombu.transport.redis.Transport.Channel.queue_order_strategy), it will then:

> Consume from queues in original order, so that if the first queue always contains messages, the rest of the queues in the list will never be consumed from.

After updating the configuration:

```py
celery_app.conf.update(broker_transport_options={"queue_order_strategy": "priority"})
```

It is necessary as a second step to start the worker with the correct order of queues where the higher-priority one should be listed first.

```bash
celery worker -Q higher_priority_queue,other_queue
```

It is my understanding that this setup will not stop the currently running tasks from lower-priority queues when there is a new task in a higher-priority queue. It will wait for it to finish. But then it will check the higher-priority queue again. And if it contains a new task, it will run it *regardless of* whether there are more tasks in other, lower-priority queues or not.